# How to I find rows in one database table where a value of one field is NOT LIKE a value in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

My SQL knowledge is quite limited so please do bear with me!

I am trying to return rows in one table based on one of the fields NOT matching a field in another table.

One of my tables has a url and site field, say table A. The other table lists some sites, using the name of the site, table B.

e.g. table A's url field may be 'http://google.it/aaa', its name field is 'google'

In table B I have a list of sites stored under a 'site' and 'name' field. Examples below:

One entry:
Site
google.co.uk

Name
google

Another entry:
Site
google.fr

Name
google

A third entry:
Site
bing.com

Name
bing

I want to return the values in table A where the url field does not match a 'site' field in table B. To do this I need to use the 'name' field in table A to look up the 'site' value in table B - if there is no match I want the entries returned. So in this case my url is 'http://google.it/aaa' so when it checks if there's an entry for google.it in table B it wouldn't find anything and therefore return it.

I am using MySQL db and these two tables are in different schemas. I have tried with some SQL and here's what I come up with:

SELECT tablea.url, tablea.name FROM schema1.tablea inner JOIN schema2.tableb ON tablea.url NOT LIKE ('%' || tableb.site || '%')

Thanks in advance

Comment: Instead of laying out sample data as you have done there, it can be more useful if you create an example at http://sqlfiddle.com and post the link here.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT 
    tablea.url, 
    tablea.name 
FROM 
    schema1.tablea 
WHERE
    EXISTS
    (SELECT
        NULL
    FROM
        schema2.tableb
    WHERE
        tablea.name = tableb.name)
AND NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT
         NULL
    FROM
        schema2.tableb 
    WHERE
        tablea.name = tableb.name
    AND tablea.url LIKE ('%' || tableb.site || '%'))
```

This will give you all rows in tablea where there exists a row in tableb with the same name, but no row in tableb exists that has the same name and whose site contains the url from tablea.

Comment: Thank you Tobsey, that was very helpful. I forgot to add that I don't want to return links where the tablea.name is NOT IN tableb (name) - so I want to return url mismatches but the name field must be in table b. I tried modifying the final line but it didn't work: and tablea.name=tableb.name

Comment: @user2047498 I've updated the query base don your comments. I think that's right. As I said above look at using sqlfiddle to create examples because it makes it much easier to see what you are trying to do, and also for people to test their answers before posting them here.